# Android show animation when playing audio with media player

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

Currently I have implemented a simple audio player playing audio files from the device internal storage.

I was wondering if there's any way to implement some animation functionality to be shown as the media player is playing music, like the Windows Media Player does:

[image: example]

Could anyone point me in the right direction of implementing this? E.g, an external library or a tutorial on how to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

try this library:

> Takes the input from the Android MediaPlayer and displays visualizations, like in iTunes or WinAmp

https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer

[image]
[image]

another one: https://github.com/carlosrafaelgn/FPlayAndroid

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out in a while

Comment: Hi again sinpin. Do you mind if I ask you how to start working with that first link you provided? I'm new at working with external libraries :-)